# Why does realloc create two different pointers?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, realloc

I have a pointer array named **lines, each line being 100 character long.

And have a function which adds characters to any given line and reallocates the line if it's not big enough:

```
void add_letter(char *line, int pos, char letter) {
    if(strlen(line) % 100 == 0){
        line = realloc(line, sizeof(char) * strlen(line) + 100);
    }
    ...
```

`add_letter` is called like this:

```
add_letter(lines[0], pos, ch);
```

line here is equal to `lines[0]`, and in the  second line, gdb returns `1` for `p line == lines[0]`.
Here `line` and `lines[0]` are both in memory location `0x6465e0`.

But after the `realloc` call, `line` becomes `0x648200`, but `lines[0]` stays in the same and becomes an `""` empty string.

What causes `realloc` to act like this? Because of this reason, `strcat(line, newline)`, `newline` being the end result of addition doesn't work at the end of the function.

Comment: "What causes `realloc` to act like this?" Um... But that's exactly what `realloc` does! That's what `realloc` is for. In general case it allocates a *new* memory block at *new* memory location. How else did you expect it to behave?

Comment: I am using C. Not C++.

Comment: @AnT but it doesn't change lines[0] but changes line, they are the same thing.

Comment: @razorx Don't tag C++ then.

Comment: @BaummitAugen same problem can apply to C++ as well.

Comment: @razorx: That has nothing to do with `realloc`. And no `line` and `line[0]` are not "the same thing". These are two completely unrelated, independent pointers that just happened to point to the same spot in memory. Then you decided to change one of them, while not changing the other. So, they became different. If you want to update `lines[0]` as well - it is your responsibility.

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.2.2 Function calls 4 An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call
to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the
corresponding argument. 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the
arguments.[...]*

Comment: @AnT that may be it, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @razorx: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong here:

> Here `line` and `lines[0]` are both in memory location 0x6465e0.

Both variables have **value** `0x6465e0`, but they are in different locations.
When you call `realloc` with `line`, runtime deallocates memory that `line` pointed to (which is `0x6465e0`), allocates new memory and puts its address in `line` - that is `0x648200`. **Value** of `lines[0]` is not influenced by this operation, but the memory where it is pointing has been freed already.
Bottom line - if you reallocate you need to update **all** pointers that pointed to the old location with the new location

Hope this helps